# Query não retorna todos os dados do registro

Tags: php, sql, aplicação-web, cakephp, cakephp-2

A seguinte query retorna o registro correto, porém faltam itens em seu retorno.

```
$nota = $this->Nota->find('first', [
    'conditions' => ['id' => $numero,
        'serie' => $serie
    ]
]);
```

Por exemplo: Quando não da erro, retorna o array completo

```
array {
    ["id"] => "1"
    ["nome"] => "nome"
    ["serie"] => "serie"
    ["texto"] => "texto"
}
```

Quando da erro, retorna o array incompleto

```
array {
    ["id"] => "2"
    ["serie"] => "serie2"
    ["nome"] => "nome2"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se forem campos do mesmo model/tabela como você diz, é possível passar a lista dos campos que você quer. Por exemplo:

```
$nota = $this->Nota->find('first', [
    'fields' => ['id', 'nome', 'serie', 'texto'],
    'conditions' => ['id' => $numero,
        'serie' => $serie
    ]
]);
```

Se forem campos de outro model, talvez você não tenha definido os relacionamentos corretamente.

Comment: São todos os campos da mesma tabela, porém em um momento retorna todos os campos, em outro retorna somente até certo ponto.

Comment: Tentou passar a lista como estou sugerindo?

Comment: Não é que funcionou?! Mas caso o fields seja omitido, o cake devia buscar todos os campos, alguma ideia do motivo de não ser emitido?

Comment: Não sei a causa. Talvez algum hook/filtro global alterando o fields se não estiver explícito.